# Unable to accept/reject calls programatically in Android

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, telecom-manager, telecom

I have a use-case in which I have established an app to app bluetooth connection between an Android mobile & an Android tablet. The apps running on both the devices are different.
Now, when I receive a call on my phone, I pass the details to the tablet via bluetooth.
The tablet sends the signal, via bluetooth, to the phone to accept/reject the call.

I tried the ITelephony AIDL approach but the "getITelephony" method has been restricted since Android 10.
I don't want to use the default dialer app approach.

Let me know if there's another way to achieve the same.